# FactoryGirl initialize_with multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, factories

I have a model with multiple params in initialize, one of which is used in a method on the model on instantiation:

```
def initialize(sha, message, repo)
    sha = commit.sha
    message = commit.message
    associate_with(repo)
end
```

And I'm trying to create a factory that initializes it using these params, but am getting `wrong number of arguments` errors when trying to do:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :commit do
    intialize_with { new("test_sha", "test_msg", "test_repo") }
  end
end
```

But this gives me `wrong number of arguments (0 for 3)`. Is it not possible to pass multiple args into `initialize_with`?

Answer (score 5):

Is the `initialize` method above for the `Commit` class becuase that is what you are calling `Commit.new("test_sha", "test_msg", "test_repo")`

Since I doubt that's the case this will work for `Commit`.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :commit do
    sha "test_sha"
    message "test_message"
    repo "test_repo"
    intialize_with { new(sha,message,repo) }
  end
end
```

This will call

```
Commit.new({sha: "test_sha", message: "test_message", repo: "test_repo"})
```

You will then have to initialize your other object correctly something like

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_other_class do
    initialize_with { new('test_sha', 'test_msg', 'test_repo') }
  end
end
```

Which will call `MyOtherClass.new("test_sha", "test_msg", "test_repo")` Although even this seems flawed since you are expecting `MyOtherClass` to reference a commit and are overwriting `sha` and `message` maybe more code would be useful

Comment: FYI- you can call `initialize_with { new(attributes) }` to get the same effect, using all the public attributes of the factory.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `repo` a `transient` property of the factory.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :commit do
    sha "test_sha"
    message "test_message"
    transient { repo "test_repo" }
    intialize_with { new(sha: sha, message: message, repo: repo) }
  end
end
```